# Visual feedback of long tap in UWP

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In an UWP app I strongly use the `RightTapped` event which in case of touch means a long tap.

What I want to add is some sort of visual feedback for the user, like a growing circle or something like that when the user is holding the touch.

Is there some simple approach to achieve it, or do I have to implement it using e.g. the `Holding` event?

Comment: I'd think you can use control's "Pressed" [VisualState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstate) . In the visual state, you can use some animation to add some visual feedback.